# How to move selected item from one listview to another in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am using FullRowSelect = true on my listview, how do i transfer my listview items in one form to another form with has a listview too.

Comment: Can you paste the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

on `form1`, create a `ListViewItem` as

```
ListViewItem lstItem = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
```

on `form2`, create a parameterized constructor as

```
ListViewItem lstViewItem = new ListViewItem(); //global variable
public Form2(ListViewItem lstItem)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    lstViewItem = lstItem;
}
```

call `form2` from `form1` with `ListViewItem` as

```
Form2 frm = new Form2(lstItem);
frm.Show();
```

so on `form2` you can get `ListViewItem` which was selected and pass through `form1`